# Compress each file while uploading many files to a server(HTML5)

Tags: html, compression, multipart

I have a form where user can upload multiple file. For e.g several xml files
But the requirement is to compress(gzip) each xml file, and then send it to the web server in a single multipart/mixed request. How do i specify this in html forms, so that the browser will do the same for me.

The post request should somewhat look like this;

POST /localhost:3000/abc HTTP/1.1

HOST: localhost:3000

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=1cb9ud_4afcystp-opazlj

Transfer-encoding: chunked

--1cb9ud_4afcystp-opazlj

Content-Disposition: attachment; name="XYZ"

Content-Type: text/xml

Content-Encoding: gzip

...

--1cb9ud_4afcystp-opazlj

Content-Disposition: attachment; name="ABC"

Content-Type: text/xml

Content-Encoding: gzip

...

--1cb9ud_4afcystp-opazlj